# Cloudformation macro conditional with no value

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I want to use a macro in my Cloudformation template, however I would like to use the macro only in production environment.
I see I can use a conditional statement, however the `Transform` requires a key name.

This is my template:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: [
  "AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31",
  !If [IsProduction, AddCloudWatchAlarms, !Ref "AWS::NoValue" ]
]


Parameters:
  Environment:
    Type: String
    AllowedValues:
      - prod
      - stag
      - dev
    ConstraintDescription: invalid environment, only [prod, stag, dev] are allowed


Conditions:
  IsProduction: !Equals [ !Ref Environment, prod ]
```

As you can see I am passing `AWS::NoValue`.

This is working perfectly when the I am deploying `prod` environment, however when I try to deploy in `dev` I get this error.

```
Error: Failed to create changeset for the stack: server-hosting-rust-dev, An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateChangeSet operation: Transforms defined as maps require Name key.
```

How can I achieve this?

I could modify the code of the macro to skip its processing if the environment is `dev`, but it is third party open source, it would take quite a while for my pull request to get approved or even create a fork (Which I will eventually do), so I am asking if there is a faster method to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any link to a reference which says you can use If in transform? According to [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#intrinsic-function-reference-conditions-if) If can be used in "metadata attribute, update policy attribute, and property values in the Resources section and Outputs sections of a template".

Comment: Honestly I do not have, I just tried to deploy the template and there was not complaint with the `cfn-lint` and  the deployment worked as expected.

Comment: I don't think you can use If in this scenario, though I'm not sure. Your initial attempt could work as it could just slip through the cracks in template validation, in which case it should not be relayed upon. I would try to find any working example or reference to such a usage of `If` to check how it should be used in this context or if even its possible.

Comment: I see, so I guess my approach is wrong, I will try to find valid alternatives